# Error while requesting a transaction with CXEndCallAction

Tags: voip, ios10, callkit

While requesting a CXTransaction with a CXEndCallAction, the transaction fails with error code 
Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=4 "(null)"

I was able to make a CXStartCallAction successfully. Does anyone know what this error means?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error codes for CallKit are defined in `<CallKit/CXError.h>`, and in iOS 10 Seed 4, error code 4 for domain `com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction` is defined as:

```
CXErrorCodeRequestTransactionErrorUnknownCallUUID = 4,
```

This indicates that the call UUID for the requested CXEndCallAction did not correspond to an known call. I recommend confirming that the UUID set on the CXEndCallAction matches an existing call.

Comment: Thanks, I use **reportCallWithUUID: updated** when I use start transaction.

Comment: For those who need to look up Error codes and their description checkout https://www.osstatus.com

Comment: I checked this and the callUUID is the same with the existing call. Is there any other reason to get this error code ?

Answer (score 3):

If you use

```
func reportCall(with UUID: UUID, updated update: CXCallUpdate)
```

to update `CXStartCallAction` with `CXCallUpdate` you MUST use `action.uuid`, not `action.callUUID`.

Later leads to `unknownCallUUID` error on call ending. In this case

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction)
```

does not fire.