# ios pushkit end last call before reportnewIncommingCall

Tags: swift, callkit, pushkit

im stuck in how to ending all the last call before report a new incoming call, my function work for 2 call, it mean i can end the first call before report new call

But the problem is after next report, the end call function throw error

Here is my code:

```
// Handle incoming pushes
    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
//        print("Handle incoming pushes: \(payload.dictionaryPayload)")
        
        endCall(thenReportNewCallForUuid: UUID.init())
    }
    
    func reportNewCall(uuid : UUID){
        
        let config = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "CallKitExample")
        config.includesCallsInRecents = true
        config.supportsVideo = true
        config.supportedHandleTypes = [.generic]
        config.iconTemplateImageData = UIImage(named: "logo_square")!.pngData()
        config.maximumCallGroups = 1
        config.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
        
        
        let provider = CXProvider(configuration: config)
        provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
        
        let update = CXCallUpdate()
        update.supportsHolding = false
        update.supportsGrouping = false
        update.supportsUngrouping = false
        update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: uuid.uuidString)
        update.hasVideo = true
        provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update, completion: { error in
            print("reportNewIncomingCall \(uuid) error: \(error)")
            
            UserDefaults.standard.set(uuid.uuidString, forKey: "CallUUID")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        })
    }

func endCall(thenReportNewCallForUuid : UUID) {
        
        guard let lastCallUUIDString = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "CallUUID"), !lastCallUUIDString.isEmpty  else{
            return
        }
        print("end uuid: \(lastCallUUIDString)")
        let call = UUID.init(uuidString: lastCallUUIDString)!
        
        let controller = CXCallController()
        let endTransaction = CXEndCallAction(call: call)
        let transaction = CXTransaction(action: endTransaction)
        controller.request(transaction, completion: { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("endcall Error: \(error)")
                self.reportNewCall(uuid: thenReportNewCallForUuid)
            } else {
                print("endcall Success")
                self.reportNewCall(uuid: thenReportNewCallForUuid)
            }
        })
    }
```

Here is log + error i got

```
end uuid: CB91CCC6-7FCD-49D3-BE93-7A6581295B57
endcall Error: Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=2 "(null)" 
-> OK first time endcall error because no call 
reportNewIncomingCall 202DB031-23AE-46B6-91E9-3FBA708E07A7 error: nil


end uuid: 202DB031-23AE-46B6-91E9-3FBA708E07A7
endcall Success -> Matched call to end -> success
reportNewIncomingCall C45FEC0B-1320-4357-ADEF-7B7CA28D96C8 error: nil


end uuid: C45FEC0B-1320-4357-ADEF-7B7CA28D96C8
endcall Error: Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=4 "(null)"
-> Matched call to end -> FAILED
reportNewIncomingCall CBDBA75A-B263-49E5-9138-8D5CCA28ED9E error: nil
```

Some one who mark duplicate please show the right answer? Thanks

Does someone facing same problem? Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while requesting a transaction with CXEndCallAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793722/error-while-requesting-a-transaction-with-cxendcallaction)

Comment: nope bro, as i have 3 call continual, first -> second (i success end the first call the report second incoming call) -> third (error end second call) -> i have 2 call screen, then need to press 2 time to dismiss 2 call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least a couple of issues in your code. But, before that, why are you ending the ongoing call whenever you receive a new incoming call? I'm just curious, because it doesn't seem to be a great user experience.

Anyway, the issues I've found are the following:

- At every new incoming call you instantiate a new `CXProvider`. As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxprovider):

> A VoIP app should create only one instance of CXProvider and store it for use globally.

- You don't invoke the completion handler of the `pushRegistry(_:didReceiveIncomingPushWith:type:completion)` method. You should invoke it inside the completion handler of the `reportNewIncomingCall(with:update:completion:)` method.

I think that the errors you're facing are caused by the `CXProvider` issue. But if you don't fix also the second issue you could incur in another problem: the system will suppose that you haven't reported a new incoming call and so, after a few calls, it will stop to send you new VoIP pushes ([this limitation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate/2875784-pushregistry) was first introduced in iOS 13).

Answer (score 1):

i've had the same issue and fixed it by moving the instantiation of CXProvider, CXProfiderConfiguration and CXCallController outside of pushRegistry function and inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions part of AppDelegate, something like this:

```
private func voipRegistration() {
    // Create a push registry object
    let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
    let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)
    voipRegistry.delegate = self
    voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]
    config.iconTemplateImageData = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cometchat_white").pngData()
    config.includesCallsInRecents = false
    config.ringtoneSound = "ringtone.caf"
    config.supportsVideo = false
    provider = CXProvider.init(configuration: config)
    provider!.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
   
}
```

You have to have a single instance of CXProvider.